# How does calling a web service from a .net app work?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, service

I added a web service as reference to a project and gave it name "days". But I don't actually understand how to work with it. Can someone show me the way how to get data from it?

In posh I get data from a web service this way:

```
$ws= New-WebServiceProxy -uri $xmld.Root.WebService.Address -credential $cred

$xml = $ws.getdays()

$xml
```

[image]

Comment: You wrote "i dont't actually understand how to call it in .net project". But the example is in PowerShell. It's confusing. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: i want do the same in .net app. i know how to call it in PoSh. now i want to know how to do it properly in .net app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at

- [Walkthrough: Calling XML Web
  Services from Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scf355x6(VS.71).aspx)
- [Creating a .NET Web Service](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/010430.htm)
- [Walkthrough: Accessing an XML Web
  Service Using Visual Basic or Visual
  C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5th1ba(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: ok. i add service reference. look what i got after adding it:
http://i50.tinypic.com/2iw94qt.png

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, you don’t need to write a client application to test a web service because .NET includes a test web page that ASP.NET uses automatically when you request the URL of an .asmx file in a browser. This page uses reflection to read and show information about the web services, such as the names of the methods it provides.

To try the test page, request the xyz.asmx file of the web service in your browser. (In Visual Studio, you simply need to set this as the start page for your application and then run it.)

Comment: i already know that my service works fine. i dont't actually understand how to call it in .net project. i added service reference and i dont know what to do with it next.